# Multithreaded Groovy Mandelbrot

Tags: image, community-challenge, groovy, fractals

Seeing as it's October, I thought I'd do the [community challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5998/49895). Due to my inexperience coding in Groovy, I decided to give Groovy a go. I'm not sure how well I followed Groovy conventions, and the rendering is quite slow. It seem that the slow rendering might have to do with locking when writing to the `BufferredImage`, or so my profiling seems to suggest.

I'm not concerned about the GUI portion (**MandelbrotViewer.groovy**); that's just there to make it possible to display the Mandelbrot.

**Mandelbrot.groovy**

```
package mandelbrot

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

import java.awt.*
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

class Mandelbrot {
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @ToString
    static class RenderDetails {
        double xMin
        double xMax
        double yMin
        double yMax
        int width
        int height
        int maxIteration
        double bailoutRadius
        def palette
        def interpolationFunction
        boolean interpolate

        public RenderDetails(Map hash) {
            xMin = hash.get("xMin", -2.5) as double
            xMax = hash.get("xMax", 1) as double
            yMin = hash.get("yMin", -1) as double
            yMax = hash.get("yMax", 1) as double
            width = hash["width"] as int
            height = hash["height"] as int
            maxIteration = hash.get("maxIteration", 1000) as int
            bailoutRadius = hash.get("bailoutRadius", 1 << 8) as double
            interpolate = hash.get("interpolate", true)
            interpolationFunction = hash.get("interpolationFunction", Mandelbrot.&linearColorInterpolation)
            palette = hash.get("palette", getDefaultPalette(interpolate ? maxIteration + 2 : maxIteration + 1))
        }
    }

    static BufferedImage render(details) {
        if (!(details instanceof RenderDetails)) {
            details = new RenderDetails(details)
        }
        def retval
        GParsPool.withPool {
            // Note: If this is not declared *here*, GParsPool locks on
            // the image each time we write to a pixel, making the
            // multithreading completely counterproductive
            def image = new BufferedImage(details.width, details.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            (0..image.width - 1).collect { x ->
                (0..image.height - 1).collect { y ->
                    [x, y]
                }
            }.sumParallel()
                    .eachParallel { px, py ->
                def x = scaleToReals(details.xMin, details.xMax, details.width, px)
                def y = scaleToReals(details.yMin, details.yMax, details.height, py)
                image.setRGB(px as int, py as int, getColor(x, y, details) as int)
            }
            retval = image
        }
        return retval
    }

    def private static getColor(double x, double y, RenderDetails details) {
        def p0 = new Complex(x, y)
        def p = new Complex(x, y)
        def curIteration = 0

        while (p.absSquare() < details.bailoutRadius**2 && curIteration < details.maxIteration) {
            p = p.square() + p0
            curIteration++
        }

        if (details.interpolate) {
            if (curIteration < details.maxIteration) {
                def log_zn = Math.log(p.absSquare()) / 2
                def nu = Math.log(log_zn / Math.log(2)) / Math.log(2)
                curIteration = curIteration + 1 - nu
            } else {
                return details.palette.get(details.palette.size() - 1).getRGB()
            }

            def color1 = details.palette.get(Math.floor(curIteration) as int)
            def color2 = details.palette.get(Math.floor(curIteration + 1) as int)
            return details.interpolationFunction(color1, color2, curIteration % 1)
        } else {
            return details.palette.get(curIteration).getRGB()
        }
    }

    def private static getDefaultPalette(size) {
        def final START = Color.ORANGE
        def final END = Color.BLACK
        def palette = []

        def rgbStep = (START.getRGB() - END.getRGB()) / (size - 1);

        (0..size - 1).each { i ->
            palette.push(
                    new Color(
                            ((START.getRGB() - (int) (rgbStep * i)) & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
                            ((START.getRGB() - (int) (rgbStep * i)) & 0x00FF00) >>> 8,
                            ((START.getRGB() - (int) (rgbStep * i)) & 0x0000FF) >>> 0
                    )
            )
        }

        return palette
    }

    @CompileStatic
    private static int linearColorInterpolation(Color c1, Color c2, double ratio) {
        new Color(
                (c1.red + (c2.red - c1.red) * ratio) as int,
                (c1.green + (c2.green - c1.green) * ratio) as int,
                (c1.blue + (c2.blue - c1.blue) * ratio) as int
        ).getRGB()
    }

    @CompileStatic
    private static double scaleToReals(double min, double max, double width, double value) {
        min + value / width * (max - min)
    }
}
```

**Complex.groovy**

```
package mandelbrot

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import groovy.transform.ToString

@Immutable
@CompileStatic
@ToString(includes = ["real", "imaginary"])
class Complex {
    public static final Complex ZERO = new Complex(0, 0)
    public static final Complex ONE = new Complex(1, 0)
    public static final Complex I = new Complex(0, 1)
    public static final double EQUALS_TOLERANCE = 1e-5;

    /** The real part of the complex number */
    double real
    /** The imaginary part of the complex number */
    double imaginary

    /** Adds the two complex numbers together */
    Complex plus(Complex other) {
        new Complex(real + other.real, imaginary + other.imaginary)
    }

    /** Subtracts the two complex numbers */
    Complex minus(Complex other) {
        new Complex(real - other.real, imaginary - other.imaginary)
    }

    /** Multiplies the two complex numbers */
    Complex multiply(Complex other) {
        new Complex(real * other.real - imaginary * other.imaginary, real * other.imaginary + imaginary * other.real)
    }
    /** Divides the two complex numbers */
    Complex div(Complex other) {
        new Complex(
                (real * other.real + imaginary * other.imaginary) / (other.real**2 + other.imaginary**2),
                (imaginary * other.real - real * other.imaginary) / (other.real**2 + other.imaginary**2)
        )
    }

    /** negate the complex number */
    Complex negative() {
        return new Complex(-real, -imaginary)
    }

    /** Complex conjugate */
    Complex conj() {
        new Complex(real, -imaginary)
    }

    /** The modulus of the complex number */
    double abs() {
        Math.sqrt(absSquare())
    }

    /** The square of the modulus */
    double absSquare() {
        real * real + imaginary * imaginary
    }

    /** The square of the complex number */
    Complex square() {
        new Complex(real * real - imaginary * imaginary, 2 * real * imaginary)
    }

    /** The reciprocal of the complex number */
    Complex reciprocal() {
        new Complex(real / absSquare(), -imaginary / absSquare())
    }

    Complex power(int n) {
        if (n == -1) {
            return reciprocal()
        } else if (n < 0) {
            return reciprocal()**-n
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return ONE
        } else if (n == 1) {
            return this
        } else if (n == 2) {
            return square()
        } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return square()**(n.intdiv(2) as int)
        } else {
            return this * square()**((n - 1).intdiv(2) as int)
        }
    }

    boolean equals(o) {
        if (this.is(o)) return true
        if (!(o instanceof Complex)) return false

        Complex complex = (Complex) o

        if (Math.abs(imaginary - complex.imaginary) > EQUALS_TOLERANCE) return false
        if (Math.abs(real - complex.real) > EQUALS_TOLERANCE) return false

        return true
    }
}
```

**MandelbrotViewer.groovy**

```
package mandelbrot

import javax.swing.*

JFrame frame = new JFrame()
frame.defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
frame.iconImage = Mandelbrot.render(
        xMin: -2,
        xMax: 1,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        maxIteration: 100,
        bailoutRadius: 2,
        interpolate: false
)

frame.add(
        new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                Mandelbrot.render(
                        width: 500,
                        height: 500
                )
        ))
)
frame.pack()
frame.locationByPlatform = true
frame.visible = true
```

Output:

[image: Mandelbrot output - Windows 10]